# Angular 2 pass array into directive via attribute not variable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

Working my own custom component and stuck with how to make it use both attributes and variables. I'm using @Input attribute directives and this works when I pass in correctly scoped variables.

**component (this works)**

`<mycomp [arrayValue]= "someArrayVar">html</mycomp>`

but I'm not sure what I need to do to make this work??

**component (not working)**

`<mycomp arrayValue= "[1,2,3,4,5]">html</mycomp>`

my directive looks something like this...

**directive**

```
    export class MyComp implements DoCheck, OnInit {

      @Input() arrayValue: number[];
```

Would appreciate anyone who can explain how I'd implement both input alias and attributes for passing in when no variable is used and a string is passed like `"[1,2,3,4,5]"`

Comment: Are you really expecting to hard code an array in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayValue="[1,2,3,4,5]"` will pass the value you give it as a string. If you *really* want to make it possible to pass the array this way, you'll have to parse it yourself (for example, using `JSON.parse`), probably in the setter (not getter) for `arrayValue`.

```
@Input() set arrayValue(value: string | number[]) {
  if (typeof value == 'string') {
    this._arrayValue = JSON.parse(value)
  } else {
    this._arrayValue = value
  }
}
```

But the question is, why you want to do this? It's not recommended.

Comment: -1 granted this answer provides a solution to the OPs problem, however the solution implements functionality that angular already has built-in. And I feel this answer is misleading on how to address this kinds of problems and it should in no way be the accepted answer IMHO, hence -1.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is similar to your first version:

```
<mycomp [arrayValue]= "someArrayVar">html</mycomp>
```

Just use this:

```
<mycomp [arrayValue]= "[1,2,3,4,5]">html</mycomp>
```

That is keep the brackets around your directive name in order to instruct angular to treat the value as expression.